# Debug traces in Protobuf-net?

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm using Protobuf-net and from time to time have some problems, usually due to misunderstandings on my part. When these things happen, it would be very helpful if could turn on some kind of debug traces, so I can see what exactly is happening with my serialization requests.

Does anyone know about something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; at least, not without bringing the project into scope (or at least: the pdb) and tracing through it manually in the debugger.

Comment: Well, this sounds like a reasonable solution, but the problem is I'm using Protobuf-net with WCF and surrogates, and I can't really catch the point in which my code is reached. Any idea?

Comment: eventually I just put a breakpint in my surrogate, and went up the call stack.

Thanks @Marc Gravell