# Is it possible to get a more detailed error from protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Is it possible to get a more detailed error from `protobuf-net`?

I see that something wrong with `Channelizer`, but it's a huge class, I've checked it several times.

Is it possible to turn on debug logs or anything that could help to find the issue?

```
ProtoBuf.ProtoException: Unable to resolve sub-type of: AE.DataModel.IssueStore (Intelsat.AE.OperationalDataModel.Channelizer) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve sub-type of: AE.DataModel.IssueStore
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.FindOrAddAuto(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean addWithContractOnly, Boolean addEvenIfAutoDisabled)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.FindOrAddAuto(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean addWithContractOnly, Boolean addEvenIfAutoDisabled)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.ApplyDefaultBehaviour()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.FindOrAddAuto(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean addWithContractOnly, Boolean addEvenIfAutoDisabled)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKey(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean getBaseKey)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.GetKey(Type type, Boolean demand, Boolean getBaseKey)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.TryGetCoreSerializer(RuntimeTypeModel model, DataFormat dataFormat, Type type, WireType& defaultWireType, Boolean asReference, Boolean dynamicType, Boolean overwriteList, Boolean allowComplexTypes)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.ValueMember.BuildSerializer()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.BuildSerializer()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.MetaType.get_Serializer()
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Serialize(Int32 key, Object value, ProtoWriter dest)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.SerializeCore(ProtoWriter writer, Object value)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Serialize(Stream dest, Object value, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize[T](Stream destination, T instance)
enter code here
```

Update

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class Channelizer : UniqueDataAccessBase, IChannelizer
{
    public Channelizer()
    {
        this.ReceivePorts = new Dictionary<string, ChannelizerReceivePort>();
        this.TransmitPorts = new Dictionary<string, ChannelizerTransmitPort>();
        this.LimiterPowerMargins = new List<LimiterPowerMargin>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, ChannelizerReceivePort> ReceivePorts { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, ChannelizerTransmitPort> TransmitPorts { get; set; }

    public double InputPortPowerMaxWarning { get; set; }

    public double InputPortPowerMaxError { get; set; }

    public double OutputPortPowerMaxWarning { get; set; }

    public double OutputPortPowerMaxError { get; set; }

    public double MaxGain { get; set; }

    public double SalcDeltaMarg { get; set; }

    public double SalcRange { get; set; }

    public double RefFrontEndlossAvg { get; set; }

    public double RefBackEndlossAvg { get; set; }

    public List<LimiterPowerMargin> LimiterPowerMargins { get; set; }
}
```

UniqueDataAccessBase

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
[ProtoInclude(10000, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AdjacentCarrierCommon")]
[ProtoInclude(10200, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AdjacentTransmitEarthStationAntenna")]
[ProtoInclude(10300, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AdjacentConnectivityLink")]
[ProtoInclude(10400, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Amplifier")]
[ProtoInclude(10500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AmplifierModel")]
[ProtoInclude(10600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Beam")]
[ProtoInclude(10700, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Block")]
[ProtoInclude(10800, "AE.OperationalDataModel.BlockLeg")]
[ProtoInclude(10900, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Device")]
[ProtoInclude(11000, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Carrier")]
[ProtoInclude(11100, "AE.OperationalDataModel.CarrierDestination")]
[ProtoInclude(11200, "AE.OperationalDataModel.CarrierDownlink")]
[ProtoInclude(11300, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Network")]
[ProtoInclude(11400, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Channelizer")]
[ProtoInclude(11500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Connection")]
[ProtoInclude(11600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.ConnectivityLink")]
[ProtoInclude(11700, "AE.OperationalDataModel.EarthStationAntenna")]
[ProtoInclude(11800, "AE.OperationalDataModel.EarthStationAntenna")]
[ProtoInclude(11900, "AE.OperationalDataModel.PayloadChain")]
[ProtoInclude(12000, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Satellite")]
[ProtoInclude(12200, "AE.OperationalDataModel.SubChannel")]
[ProtoInclude(12300, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Switch")]
[ProtoInclude(12400, "AE.OperationalDataModel.TransmissionParameter")]
[ProtoInclude(12500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Channel")]
[ProtoInclude(12600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.ChannelizerPort")]
public class UniqueDataAccessBase : IssueStore, IUniqueDataAccessBase
{
    public UniqueDataAccessBase()
        : this("Id")
    {
    }

    public UniqueDataAccessBase(string idPropName)
    {
        this.Id = Constants.NullString;
        this.IdPropertyName = idPropName;
    }

    public DatabaseCompletion DatabaseCompletionMethod { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; } // tdb_amp_id

    public string IdPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

ChannelizerReceivePort

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
public class ChannelizerReceivePort : ChannelizerPort
{
    public ChannelizerReceivePort()
    {
        this.Channels = new List<ReceiveChannel>();
        this.Measurements = new List<ChannelizerReceivePortMeasurement>();
    }

    public List<ReceiveChannel> Channels { get; set; }

    public List<ChannelizerReceivePortMeasurement> Measurements { get; set; }
}
```

ChannelizerPort

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(100, typeof(ChannelizerReceivePort))]
[ProtoInclude(200, typeof(ChannelizerTransmitPort))]
public abstract class ChannelizerPort : UniqueDataAccessBase, IChannelizerPort
{
}
```

UniqueDataAccessBase

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
[ProtoInclude(10000, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AdjacentCarrierCommon")]
[ProtoInclude(10200, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AdjacentTransmitEarthStationAntenna")]
[ProtoInclude(10300, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AdjacentConnectivityLink")]
[ProtoInclude(10400, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Amplifier")]
[ProtoInclude(10500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.AmplifierModel")]
[ProtoInclude(10600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Beam")]
[ProtoInclude(10700, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Block")]
[ProtoInclude(10800, "AE.OperationalDataModel.BlockLeg")]
[ProtoInclude(10900, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Device")]
[ProtoInclude(11000, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Carrier")]
[ProtoInclude(11100, "AE.OperationalDataModel.CarrierDestination")]
[ProtoInclude(11200, "AE.OperationalDataModel.CarrierDownlink")]
[ProtoInclude(11300, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Network")]
[ProtoInclude(11400, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Channelizer")]
[ProtoInclude(11500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Connection")]
[ProtoInclude(11600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.ConnectivityLink")]
[ProtoInclude(11700, "AE.OperationalDataModel.EarthStationAntenna")]
[ProtoInclude(11800, "AE.OperationalDataModel.EarthStationAntenna")]
[ProtoInclude(11900, "AE.OperationalDataModel.PayloadChain")]
[ProtoInclude(12000, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Satellite")]
[ProtoInclude(12200, "AE.OperationalDataModel.SubChannel")]
[ProtoInclude(12300, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Switch")]
[ProtoInclude(12400, "AE.OperationalDataModel.TransmissionParameter")]
[ProtoInclude(12500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.Channel")]
[ProtoInclude(12600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.ChannelizerPort")]
public class UniqueDataAccessBase : IssueStore, IUniqueDataAccessBase
{
    public UniqueDataAccessBase()
        : this("Id")
    {
    }

    public UniqueDataAccessBase(string idPropName)
    {
        this.Id = Constants.NullString;
        this.IdPropertyName = idPropName;
    }

    public DatabaseCompletion DatabaseCompletionMethod { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string IdPropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

IssueStore

```
[ProtoContract(ImplicitFields = ImplicitFields.AllPublic)]
[ProtoInclude(10100, "AE.DataModel.DataAccessBase")]
[ProtoInclude(10200, "AE.Common.Model.UniqueDataAccessBase")]
[ProtoInclude(10400, "AE.Common.Model.UniqueDataAccessBase")]
[ProtoInclude(10500, "AE.OperationalDataModel.BeamBwSegment")]
[ProtoInclude(10600, "AE.OperationalDataModel.FrequencyRange")]
public class IssueStore : IIssueStore, IStateChecker
{
    public IssueStore()
    {
        this.Issues = new List<Error>();
    }

    public List<Error> Issues { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the full picture

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at the schema that was generated for your type by doing `ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.GetSchema(typeof(Channelizer)))`, perhaps you'll spot the problem.  Protobuf-net doesn't implement debug tracing though, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29674382/3744182).

Comment: That means that a [ProtoInclude] specified something that couldn't be found. Is there any code I can look at here?

Comment: @MarcGravell please take a look on the updated question

Comment: @dbc the `GetSchema(typeof(Chan‌nelizer))` doesn't return too much, only `Unable to resolve sub-type of: AE.DataModel.IssueStore`, so it says that there's a problem, not much :(

Comment: @MarcGravell looks like I've to use full path as a `KnownTypeName`. Did not help. Is there any trick if classes are in different assembly?

Comment: @GSerjo if you aren't using `typeof`, then you need to use the **assembly qualified** name (AQN, which is available on `Type`). Alternatively, IIRC there is an inbuilt type resolver API if you want to do something bespoke, but I don't remember the details off the top of my head. Give me a shout if the AQN approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MarcGravell said in the comment "if you aren't using typeof, then you need to use the assembly qualified name (AQN, which is available on Type)."

So, try to use

1. `typeof`, if not possible `goto 2`
2. use assembly qualified name, you can get it from `typeof(int).Type`

BTW: be sure, you are using the latest version. [protobuf-net 2.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/2.3.0) is a debug-friendly version